# Rails cache Permission Denied when cache is very large

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

My app uses extensive rails caching, and all the cache keys are created and used by the same application, which has full rights to the cache folder.

However, occasionally when the cache gets particularly large (large uptick in use within the cache expiration window), I start getting permissions errors when accessing the cache fragments using Rails.cache.fetch:

```
Permission denied @ unlink_internal
```

Clearing the cache "fixes" the problem, until it gets large again.  Is there a theoretical limit to the size such a cache can be, or could there be some other cause?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my assessment of the cause was incorrect.  I had some tasks being run with elevated privileges, and thus their cache keys were written with elevated privileges, and due to the way cache folders are randomly generated, eventually a cache key from the "main application" would try to write there and could not due to permissions.  Ensuring that the same user ran all related tasks fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you explain "elevated privileges"?

Comment: @KazimZaidi sorry, the scheduled tasks were being run on the OS as root, or at least as sudo'd user.  The user that "ran" the main ruby instance had lower privileges, and since fragment caching is done on the file system, they could not write or delete expired fragments due to file permissions, which caused a fatal error.